# Elasticsearch - tf-idf computation for each alias in shard

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-opendistro

Considering I have three customer accounts and the data of three accounts are stored in three aliases in the single index which is distributed across three shards.

For a given query, how is the tf-idf calculated? Since it is in the single index does the term count is considered with all three account's data/aliases. I would like to know if we can restrict the term frequency count and IDF only to the account/one alias

Answer (score 0):

If you are using routing with your aliases it will use specific routing to find the shards and will calculate the tf-idf on that specific shards otherwise your tf-idf is calculated based on index.
For more information you can check custom routing in ElasticSearch [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/customizing-your-document-routing) and [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-routing-field.html).

**Update:**

Index and shard definitions:

> Data in Elasticsearch is organized into indices. Each index is made up of one or more shards. Each shard is an instance of a Lucene index, which you can think of as a self-contained search engine that indexes and handles queries for a subset of the data in an Elasticsearch cluster.

Comment: Hey thnx, so as per my understanding the tf-idf is calculated per shard. Is there a way to route a search only to a particular index such that tf-idf is calculated based on the documents presented in that index ignoring other indices for tf-idf calculation in the same shard?

Comment: Each shard only points to one index but index can have many shards, so when your search routed to specific shard your tf-idf calculated in this shard only. Also you can use filter in your query if you want to filter documents.

Comment: I updated my answer for describing better shards and indices.